# Approaches for forecasting higher frequency data with mixed (high and low) freq exogenous variables?

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, midas

I have `y` data at a daily frequency and a number of `x` variables at daily, weekly and monthly intervals.  I'm looking to create a multiple linear regression from these.

I'm familiar with MIDAS methods, but these typically prescribe using higher frequency `x` vars with lower freq `y` variables.

Have considered simply up/downsampling approaches, but averages or linear interpolation is likely to defeat the purpose of attempting the regression in the first place.

There appear to be a few applicable R packages ([tempdisagg](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tempdisagg/index.html), [tsibbledata](https://github.com/tidyverts/tsibbledata)) and also found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/85596/forecasting-high-frequency-variable-with-low-frequency-predictor) and [this](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0169207018300967), but wonder if someone more familiar with this kind of work can advise what tends to be de facto aside from trying a bunch of approaches and seeing what works/is feasible.  As this seems like a common enough problem wondering if there are common enough approaches to start with.

Working primarily with Python but seems like R may be more appropriate for actual implementation.

Comment: Your question is a bit borderline for CV. It appears you are looking for the right statistical approach but also which package may be necessary to accomplish that. Programming questions are typically off-topic here unless the query is specifically about the statistics behind the approach (such as an explanation of why certain forecasting methods may be suitable for you), which I reckon your question is more about. I would clarify that or else this question may be closed or moved to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand, concerned just with approach for the time being.  Reference to programming/packages is more secondary (and an attempt to show what I've looked at/attempted thus far)